# Facing an issue of accessing api request from remote system

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

My full stack application is working fine but when i tried to access it from remote system it couldn't get rest api call. Here i'm providing the code of Cors configuration and some of the code for your reference. Please verify and suggest me the solution.

React app code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import axios from 'axios'
import './index.css'

const itemType = {
    'ASSET':'ASSET',
    'EXPENSE':'EXPENSE'
}

const ItemMaster = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        itemName: '',
        itemBrand: '',
        itemModel: '',
        itemCapacity: '',
        itemType: 'ASSET'

    });

    const [message,setMessage] = useState('')
    const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([])

useEffect (() => {
    fetchData()
}, [])

const fetchData = async() => {
   const option = {
        method: 'GET'
    }
  
    await axios.get("http://localhost:8089/items", option).then(response => setItemList(response.data)).catch(error => 
    {if(error.response){
        console.error("Server responded with status", error.response.status)
    }else if(error.request){
        console.error("No response recived from server", error.request )
    }
    else{
        console.error('Error:', error.message )
    }

    })
   
  
}

const handleSubmit = async(event) => {

        event.preventDefault();
        if(formData.itemName !== '' && formData.itemBrand !== '' && formData.itemCapacity !== '' && formData.itemModel !== '' && formData.itemType !== '' )
       {
        try{
            const isConfirmed = window.confirm("Do you want to save this record ?")
            if(isConfirmed){
            const savedData = await axios.post("http://localhost:8089/items",formData).then().catch(error => console.log(error))
            setMessage(`Successfully updated the Item and the New item id is ${savedData.data.itemId}`)

            setFormData({
                itemName: '',
                itemBrand: '',
                itemCapacity: '',
                itemModel: '',
                itemType: 'ASSET',
                    })
                }
                
        }
        catch(error){
            setMessage(`This item already exists , error :  ${error.message}`)
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    else{
        setMessage("Invalid input")
    }
        

        

                fetchData();
    };

    const handleChange = (event) => {

        setMessage('');
        
        const {name,value} = event.target;
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [name] : value.toUpperCase(),
        })
       
        
    }

    return(
<div className="item-master-container">
    <div className='item-master-form-container'>
<h1 className="item-addform-heading">Add New Item</h1>
    <form className="item-master-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        
    <label htmlFor="itemType"  className='item-master-label'> Item Type:
        
        </label>
        <select  name="itemType" className='item-master-input' value={formData.itemType} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option id={itemType.ASSET}>{itemType.ASSET}</option>
            <option id={itemType.EXPENSE}>{itemType.EXPENSE}</option>
        </select>

        <label htmlFor="itemName" className='item-master-label'> Name:
            
        </label><input type="text" name="itemName" className='item-master-input' placeholder='Enter Item Name' value={formData.itemName} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="itemBrand" className='item-master-label'> Brand:        
        
        </label><input type="text" name="itemBrand" className='item-master-input' placeholder='Enter Item Brand' value={formData.itemBrand} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="itemModel" className='item-master-label'> Model:
        
        </label><input type="text" name="itemModel" className='item-master-input' placeholder='Enter Item Model' value={formData.itemModel} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="itemCapacity" className='item-master-label'> Capacity:
        
        </label><input type="text" name="itemCapacity" className='item-master-input' placeholder='Enter Item Capacity' value={formData.itemCapacity} onChange={handleChange}/>
        
        
        <button type='submit'className='item-master-button'>Submit</button>

       {message && <p className='alert-message'>{message}</p>}
    </form>
    </div>
    <div className='item-list-container'>
        <h1 className='item-addform-heading'>Item Master Details</h1>
        <table className='item-table'>
            <thead className='item-table-heading'>
            <tr className='item-master-table-heading-row'>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>ID</th>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>Name</th>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>Brand</th>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>Model</th>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>Capacity</th>
                <th className='item-master-list-heading'>Type</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {itemList.map(each => (
                <tr className='item-master-table-row'>
                    <td className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemId}</td>
                    <td key={each.id} className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemName}</td>
                    <td className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemBrand}</td>
                    <td className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemModel}</td>
                    <td className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemCapacity}</td>
                    <td className='item-master-list-data'>{each.itemType}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}

            </tbody>
            
        </table>
        
    </div>
</div>)
}
export default ItemMaster
```

Spring boot Cors configuration settings :

```
package com.IT.Stock.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**") // Define the mapping pattern for which CORS should be configured
                .allowedOrigins("*")// Allow requests from this origin
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE") // Allow these HTTP methods
                .allowedHeaders("*") // Allow all headers
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

[This is the output where i can get in host system when i accessed the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUo9i.png)

[This is the output where i am getting in remote system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRbpc.jpg)

I have tested with postman and direct rest api url accessing in browser it is working but only the problem is i'm unable to access the rest api data through react .Please help me to fix this error.

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is not a CORS issue, it means that the target system refused the connection.

Comment: Target system giving access of api calls without any restriction for postman and direct browser access of api call with port number i.e like http://192.168.99.99:3004 , problem is only with access of rest api calls through react.

Comment: Seems like you are making a request from "a remote system" but pointing at "localhost" `await axios.post("http://localhost:8089/items",formData)`.

Comment: yes both the are hosted in single system thats y it was mentioned like that.

Comment: Yes you are correct, after replacing it is working great. Thank you.